# Executing a SQL Server stored procedure with c# linq without a DBSet

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a project at the moment and for this part that I am working on I am required to call a stored procedure that returns a `TicketNumber` string in the format `TodaysDate.Number` (e.g. `11032019.0001`).

Now this is where the problem is. The procedure works and I can call this by running a SQL statement on the database however nothing seems to have worked when trying to run this with C# in the controller.

I currently have this:

```
var NewOrderIdOut = new SqlParameter("@NewOrderIdOut", "");
var result = await db.Tickets.SqlQuery("[dbo].[usp_NewOrderId] @NewOrderIdOut", NewOrderIdOut).SingleAsync();
```

Stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_NewOrderId 
    (@NewOrderIdOut CHAR(13) OUTPUT ) 
AS 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM OrderNumberGenerator 
               WHERE CreatedDate <> CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
        TRUNCATE TABLE OrderNumberGenerator   -- restart the counter everyday :)

    INSERT INTO OrderNumberGenerator 
    DEFAULT VALUES

    SELECT @NewOrderIdOut =
           CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) +
           RIGHT( '.000' + CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)  
END
```

I get this error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'PSARMM.Models.Ticket'. A member of the type, 'TicketId', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Only problem is the procedure doesn't return all the parameters that are in the model just the single ticketNumber string so an error gets thrown.

Another problem, I can't use `db.ExecuteSqlCommand` because I can't install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` because there are some incompatible files according to nuget.

I could create a new table just used to temporarily store this new `ticketNumber` I am creating but felt there is probably a better way so am reaching out to see if you all have any genius ideas :D

As for direction of the parameter, I have no idea.

Cheers

EDIT: I ended up scrapping this idea and instead used a trigger within the table itself to call the procedure and put the result into the new row in the correct column. And it worked like a charm.

Comment: Where are you getting the error and what is the error? How is your stored procedure defined? Do you need to set the parameter direction of the sql parameter to OUTPUT?

Comment: Updated with some more info let me know if more is needed

Comment: I'm not sure about your EF error but you should set you sql paramter direction to `ParameterDirection.Output`

Comment: What's about stepping off from EF and use just "raw" SqlCommand class?

Comment: Your query is in the scope of the Tickets db set and is therefore trying to turn the results of the stored procedure into Tickets. If you just want to run a sql command I believe you would do it from the base context: `db.Database.SqlQuery....`.

Comment: @Crowcoder That allowed me to run the procedure which was great but a new problem came up as the returned value was empty. I don't know if that had anything to do with that or not just yet. NOTE: I did also set the direction to output.

Comment: It is possible for ScopeIdentity to return NULL. And from what you described, you don't need a trigger, so using it hides functionality from the code for no reason. And is considered a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

> Another problem, I can't use db.ExecuteSqlCommand because

Sure you can.

Available in both [EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0), and [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommand?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions_ExecuteSqlCommand_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RawSqlString_System_Object___), DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand is the correct method for calling a stored procedure that doesn't return a resultset mapped to an Entity.

So something like:

```
var NewOrderIdOut = new SqlParameter("@NewOrderIdOut",System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
NewOrderIdOut.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

var result = await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("exec [dbo].[usp_NewOrderId] @NewOrderIdOut output", NewOrderIdOut);
```

Comment: Turns out I was missing the Database keyword in db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand. By adding the keyword Database in I could call the procedure but ran into more problems so changed the solution in the end.